# Submitting modal pop up form and another form simultaneously

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I have two forms. One is in a modal pop up and one is in the page beneath.  I want to submit them simultaneously using this code:

```
$('.window .submitlink').click(function (e) {
    $('#form2').submit();                            
    $('#form1').submit();
});
```

But one problem exists, and that is: it does not process the page in the action of `form2`, and it simply processes the action in `form1`.

By the way I am doing this in wordpress.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can set the `target` attribute on (one of) the form(s), directing the submission to a frame, or a new page (`_blank`).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to dynamically create a post using the content from each form.  First you need to parameterize the forms and then post that data through $.post or $.ajax

For example:
    var data = {};

```
$('#form1 input').each(function () {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
}

$('#form2 input').each(function () {
    data[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
}
$.post('mytarget/address/topost/to', data);
```

This assumes you are posting to the same place.  If not, you'll have to use separate $.post statements.

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior for HTML forms (what you're triggering with the `.submit()` is to immediately follow the form's action upon the completion of the initial action.  To override that, you have to take steps to make it work as you'd expect it, doing one submit after the other.

The challenge with your current process is that you're not allowing for any feedback should the submit fail.  There's no indicator resulting from the submit that allows the view to notify the user that there's an issue, nor is there anything there to prevent the second from blindly submitting if the first one fails.

Two ways you could attempt to make this happen:

1. Combine the forms.  Perhaps this goes against your code design, however
2. Nest Ajax submits.  This allows you to get dynamic "feedback" to the view and start/stop the second submission based on the success of the first, with no default action overriding number 2.

Some considerations:

- if you use a button inside the form, it will submit the form by default unless you do an "override default"
- If you go the ajax route, use `.serialize()` on your form to get the values without having to specify them id by id